# How to use grep -f only with variables as input like in echo "pattern" | grep -f - <<< $var?

Tags: linux, bash, syntax, grep

The following code syntax works:

```
echo "pattern_list" | grep -f - "/path/to/file"
```

and also

```
grep -f "/path/to/pattern/file" <<< $variable_that_holds_file_content
```

but is it possible that grep -f works only with variables?

Because

```
echo "pattern_list" | grep -f - <<< $variable_that_holds_file_content
```

is not working.

Could you show me how? THX!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution ( untested ):

```
grep -f <( echo "pattern_list"  )  <<< $variable_that_holds_file_content
```

The problem with your third expression is that you are telling grep to read stdin ( that is -f - ) for the pattern file AND the file content on stdin.  You can't do both.  If you are using stdin for patterns you'll need to have grep open files ( it's arguments ) to parse content ( that's why your first example works ).  Or you can have grep open the file containing the patterns and parse input from stdin ( that's why the second case works ).

Comment: Wow - very fast answer that works - testet! Thx you very much!